# Hi, can anyone help me understand what is happening in this code?

Tags: python

I know this is a recursive function that returns the number of ways to represent a number `n` as the sum of the numbers which are not greater than `k`, in order, but I can't understand how it's done.

```
def all_sums(n, k):

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n < 0: 
        return 0
    else:
        res = 0
        for i in range(1, k+1):
            res = res + all_sums(n-i, k)
        return res
```

Comment: Why don't you use `pdb` or add some `print` statements to watch things change? This is a very basic recursion and you probably just need to read more about recursion in general.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should know that this function is recursive. Basically what that means is that the code calls itself, with different numbers. A good example of recursion is the [fibbonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) sequence, which adds the two previous numbers in the sequence together to get the next number. The code for that would be :

```
def F(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0 #base case no.1 because there are no previous elements to add together.
    elif n == 1:
        return 1 #base case no.2 because there are not enough previous elements to add together.
    else:
        return F(n-1)+F(n-2) #adds together the result of whatever the last number in the sequence was to whatever the number before that was.
```

Once you understands how recursion works, you can simply trace through the code. If this is hard to do mentally, try drawing it out on a piece of paper. I find that this can be a helpful strategy in general when programming anything. I always keep a pad of paper and a pencil nearby my computer for this reason. Let's do a quick run-down of the code together, just to get the general idea of what's happening:

```
def all_sums(n,k):
```

Here, we are defining the method, and passing to arguments, `n` and `k` to it.

```
if n == 0:
    return 1
```

This is a "base case" for the recursive function, essentially there to make sure that the code won't run forever, and to close up the function.

```
elif n < 0:
    return 0
```

This shows that if `n` is less than 0, return 0 (because `n` can't be negative). This is considered a "special case" to prevent someone from accidentally screwing up the program.

```
else:
    res = 0
```

If none of the other "special cases" happen, do all the following. First, we set a variable equal to 0.

```
for i in range(1, k+1):
    res = res + all_sums(n-i, k)
```

calls a for loop that starts at 1 and goes through each integer up to (but not including) `k+1`. For each iteration, it sets our `res` variable to whatever `res` was before *plus* the result of calling the same function, using `n-i` as the first variable.

```
return res
```

this code simply outputs whatever the result is for res after the for loop completes.

If you want to see how the code works, add `print` statements to various parts of the code and watch what it outputs. Also, you may want to read up on [recursion](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/recursionsimple.html) a bit, if this confuses you at all.

**EDIT**

Here is a basic run through of `all_sums(3,3)`, using pseudo-code. First, however, here is your code with a few comments and print statements added (this was the code I ran in a file called "test.py":

```
def all_sums(n, k):

    if n == 0: #base case 1
        return 1
    elif n < 0: #base case 2
        return 0
    else: #recursive case
        res = 0
        for i in range(1, k+1):
            res = res + all_sums(n-i, k)
        print res #output res to the screen
        return res

print all_sums(3,3)
```

And here is my trace of the code. Note that every time you go down a level, res is a different variable due to the scope of the variable. Every time I tab in, is when I'm running the code inside a new call to the function.

```
all_sums(3,3):
    res = 0
    0 + all_sums((3-1),3)
        res = 0
        0 + all_sums((2-1),3)
            res = 0
            0 + all_sums((1-1),3)
                returning 1 #first base case
            1 + all_sums((1-2),3)
                returning 0 #second base case
            1 + all_sums((1-3),3)
                returning 0 #second base case
            PRINTING 1 TO THE SCREEN
            returning 1 #end of recursive case
        1 + all_sums((2-2),3)
            returning 1 #first base case
        2 + all_sums((2-3),3)
            returning 0 #second base case
        PRINTING 2 TO THE SCREEN
        returning 2 #end of recursive case
    2 + all_sums((3-2),3)
        res = 0
        0 + all_sums((1-1),3)
            returning 1 #first base case
        1 + all_sums((1-2),3)
            returning 0 #second base case
        1 + all_sums((1-3),3)
            returning 0 #second base case
        PRINTING 1 TO THE SCREEN
        returning 1 #end of recursive case
    3 + all_sums((3-3),3)
        returning 1 #first base case
    PRINTING 4 TO THE SCREEN
    returning 4 #end of recursive
returning 4 #end of recursive case (and your original function call)

PRINTING 4 TO THE SCREEN AS THE RESULT OF all_sums(3,3)
```

Comment: Thank you.                                                                                              Can you show me the steps please just step by step, I start to get in trouble when I get to 0 then went to 'for'

Comment: I added in a trace to a call to `all_sums(3,3)`. Does this help clear things up a little?

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to check the problem as "solved" if this is the answer you are looking for. Good luck on your endeavors!